# why does the python int() method not like the number 05000408 in base =0

Tags: python

```
new_sn = int(sys.argv[5], 0)
```

if I pass in the number 05000408 or higher, I get

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 0: '05000408'
```

but if I pass in 05000407 or lower, or take out the leading 0, it works fine. whats magical about the number 05000408?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most languages, integer literals with preceding zeros are considered to be in [**octal notation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), which only uses the digits 0 thru 7. This means 8 is an invalid octal digit, which is why Python does not like it.

Strip the leading zero. I highly doubt you intend octal notation.

Comment: @Jonathon, why would you do that? Your current rep ends with `42`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi 42-5=37

Comment: whats special about 31337?

Comment: @Siavash I'm just being a geek: [31337 = ELEET ("elite")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet).

Answer (score 3):

It's not that 05000408 is special. It's base 0. Giving a base of 0 tells Python to treat the number as a Python int literal. Python int literals starting with 0 are considered octal, but 8 isn't a valid octal digit.

You most likely don't want octal, binary, or the other things a base of 0 will do. If you want base 10, use base 10, or don't specify the base (so it defaults to 10).

Answer (score 2):

The leading `0` indicates an octal number, for which only the digits 0-7 are valid, so the `8` is confusing Python.

If you're trying to represent a base-10 number, get rid of the second parameter to `int` (which will force it to treat all input as base-10) or the leading `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Base 0 in the [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function menas to interpret it as a Python numeric literal.

A leading zero indicates base 8 (octal), and 8 is not a digit in base 8.

When you remove the leading zero you make it interpret the number in decimal, in which 8 is a valid digit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading 0 and try again.

You'll find now it works.

Because the leading 0 indicates that it is a octal number, which only use 0~7.